# Node.js SOAP (package): how can I convert an XML example to query?

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

Unfortunately our partner has API only in XML-SOAP. It is my first experience with it.

I have example of successful request in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"

    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"

    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <soap:Body>

        <GetMessageRequest xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/inplat/servin/OpenApiMessageConsumerService/types/1.0">

            <Message>

                <tns:AuthRequest xmlns:tns="urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/ais3/kkt/AuthService/types/1.0">

                    <tns:AuthAppInfo>

                        <tns:MasterToken>[ I NEED TO SEND ONLY THIS VARIABLE ]</tns:MasterToken>

                    </tns:AuthAppInfo>

                </tns:AuthRequest>

            </Message>

        </GetMessageRequest>

    </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to understand what is what is what: what is function here (if I am understanding right - it is GetMessageRequest, correct me), what are arguments (if I understand - they are inside message, but how to type them correct).

How can I write the correct query?

My code:

```
        require('soap')
            .createClientAsync('https://openapi.nalog.ru:8090/open-api/AuthService/0.1?wsdl')
            .then(client => client.GetMessageAsync({Message: {
                AuthRequest: {
// in XML there is tns:AuthRequest
// xmlns:tns="urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/ais3/kkt/AuthService/types/1.0" 
// How to add it here correct?

                    AuthAppInfo: {

                    },
                }}})
                .then(message => log(message)).catch(err => inspect(err)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The main part of SOAP is the WSDL. With it, you can generate clients to call the services exposed.

For the main wsdl tag you can refer to [w3cshool](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_wsdl.asp)

Starting from this

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetMessage">
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetMessageRequest" name="GetMessageRequest"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetMessageResponse" name="GetMessageResponse"> </wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault message="tns:AuthenticationException" name="AuthenticationException"> </wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
```

This is a function that you can call it, and you see what request it accept, what is the response format and the fault format. A simple xsd in `type` describe the format of each message.

For your use case, this snippet is a good start:

```
const soap = require('soap');
const url = 'https://openapi.nalog.ru:8090/open-api/AuthService/0.1?wsdl';
const args = {
  GetMessageRequest:
    { Message: { AuthRequest: { AuthAppInfo: { MasterToken: 'TOKEN' } } } }
};
soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(client.describe(), null, 2));
  client.GetMessage(args, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

It produces this request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tns="urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/inplat/servin/OpenApiMessageConsumerService/1.0"
    xmlns:ns1="urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/inplat/servin/OpenApiMessageConsumerService/types/1.0">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:GetMessageRequest
            xmlns:ns1="urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/inplat/servin/OpenApiMessageConsumerService/types/1.0"
            xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/inplat/servin/OpenApiMessageConsumerService/types/1.0">
            <ns1:GetMessageRequest>
                <ns1:Message>
                    <ns1:AuthRequest>
                        <ns1:AuthAppInfo>
                            <ns1:MasterToken>TOKEN</ns1:MasterToken>
                        </ns1:AuthAppInfo>
                    </ns1:AuthRequest>
                </ns1:Message>
            </ns1:GetMessageRequest>
        </ns1:GetMessageRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

NOTE that the namespace for `AuthRequest` need to be fixed to `urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/ais3/kkt/AuthService/types/1.0`